# Why use this.setState will cause Maximum update depth exceeded?

Tags: react-native

In my class component i fetch API from `react-redux` to render my view. So i set a loading flag like this:

```
render() {
  const theData = this.props.theData;

  if(this.props.loading) {
    return (
      // Show loading view
    );
  }
  console.log('I am test message');  

  return (
    // This is real view want to show
  );
}
```

If i run this i can see my log show `I am test message` just one time, because i fetch my API succeed and re-render view then pass `if(this.props.loading)`.

Now i want to use `theData` with `this.setState`, so i try it like this:

```
render() {
      const theData = this.props.theData;

      if(this.props.loading) {
        return (
          // Show loading view
        );
      }
      console.log('I am test message');  

      // Here is what i try
      this.setState({ theData });

      return (
        // This is real view want to show
      );
    }
```

I think this.setState will run just one time too. But when i run it i see the error `Maximum update depth exceeded`

Why ? I have no idea with the situation. And if i want to use `this.setState` with avoid this error which place should be the better way ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`this.setState({ theData });` , calling this method will cause the component to be rendered again and that is why you are getting the error. Set the state with `theData` in the constructor or the API call. Also in constructor , do not use the setState method , directly assign it . Ex : `this.state = {}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if i try it in my constructor that will show `Can't call setState on an unmounted component`. Any idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't call setState in the constructor , instead directly assign it.

Comment: But constructor will not know i fetch API data succeed. How could i use `this.state ={ set data after fetch API } ` ?

Comment: You can't escape the first render where the data is not set. You'll just have to make sure it's good to render after constructor (don't do async calls here)